# How to dismiss dialogs from Application Android

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

I have just showed dialog from some specific activities. I want to dismiss showed dialog from Application, but I can't reference to the dialog instance to dismiss itself. Anyone can help me ????

MainActivity.java

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(getContext());
dialog.show();
```

MyApplication

```
mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dimen_52),
                getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dimen_52),
                android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY :
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        myButton.setImageDrawable(icon);

        myButton.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // MainActivity instance
                    // code to dismiss here
                    mainActivity.???

                    break;
            }

            return true;

        });
```

Comment: can you show the code you have used to display dialog

Comment: I have just updated my post. please review <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface

**or**

make static dialog like

```
public static FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(getContext());
```

you dismiss like

```
MainActivity.dialog.dismiss();
```